# Running example of NAppUpdate updater

Tags: c#

hi can anyone give me running example of NAPPUpdate

[NAppUPdate](http://www.code972.com/blog/2010/08/nappupdate-application-auto-update-framework-for-dotnet/)

Answer (score 4):

NAppUpdate comes with 2 sample applications, the WinForms one is fully working and commented. See here: https://github.com/synhershko/NAppUpdate/tree/master/Samples/WinFormsSampleApp.

For any other particular questions you may want to visit the discussion group at http://groups.google.com/group/nappupdate.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find an example here: http://www.code972.com/blog/2010/08/nappupdate-application-auto-update-framework-for-dotnet/